# subdirectories in org-directory for org-agenda-files

Tags: org-agenda

Somehow this works fine:

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("file1.org" "file2.org" "subdir/file4.org"))
```

and this doesn't:

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("file1.org" "file2.org" "subdir/file3.org" "subdir/file4.org"))
```

throwing `Non-existent agenda file subdir/file4.org.  [R]emove from list or [A]bort?`

Why?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that relative paths in the list of `org-agenda-files` are relative with respect to the `default-directory` of the buffer where you called `org-agenda`? Relative paths of agenda files are only relative w.r.t. the directory in `org-directory` when the value of `org-agenda-files` is a string with the path of an org-file that contains the paths of the agenda files as links.

Comment: Yes, I am. As you can see, the first snippet works fine with all the files relatively found. The problem arises when adding more elements after the one containing a slash.